# How to launch IE7 from a Windows Phone App?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

How do you launch an instance of IE from an app? Is it better practice to page to a window with and browser window?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can launch a URI in the browser using the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428757(v=VS.92).aspx).

Use it like this:

```
var wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
wbt.URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
wbt.Show();
```

Comment: Hi Sevki, I'll vote up both these since technically the same answer at the same time and both correct. Also another alternative which I'll add below for consideration even though not exactly what you've asked for.

Answer (score 13):

In Windows Phone 8, URL has been phased out. Use this instead:

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();

webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute);

webBrowserTask.Show();
```

See the documentation on the IE task at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the WebBrowserTask:

```
WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
browser.URL = "http://www.google.com";
browser.Show();
```

Answer (score 3):

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755/matt-lacey) and [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50468/olivier-payen) have already answered the question, but I was looking for this and thought some extra information would be helpful since I hate tracking down namespaces:

- You have to have a reference to the Microsoft.Phone.dll (Automatic in Silverlight Apps)
- You need to put `using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;` at the top of your class (this is the namespace where the WebBrowserTask is declared).

Then you can use the code shown above, or use this slight variation:

```
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask() { URL = "http://wirebear.com/blog" };
task.Show();
```

As long as you have handled tombstoning in your app, the user can just hit back to return which is usually the desired behavior.  Another bonus is that the loading of the browser integrates really well in WP7 so that it actually looks like it's part of your app.  The browser comes in with a turnstile animation and keeps your appBar showing for a moment then flips them to the browser icons - a very nice effect for just 2 lines of code!

Comment: You can rightclick on that and select "resolve". That should save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you are aware, you can also embed a browser within your app using WebBrowser control.

It's there in the toolbox, just drag it on your page. You can navigate with code if you want like..

```
private void webBrowser1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com/", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

Comment: If you do this beware of the possible impact on back button behaviour. - If you use the webBrowser control full screen to mimic IE the back button won't navigate back through multiple web pages as it would in IE.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Matt. Yes WebBrowser and WebBrowserTask do not perform exactly the same functions. Sevki, if you decide to look into it further you will see how they differ. This isn't posted as a competing answer, rather to make you aware of all your options... then you can decide what works for your needs.

Comment: I am aware of that. Here is my take on the issue there are pros and cons to both... you do have to do tombstoning when you redirect to an external instance and cannot display your custom controls, but the embedded version doens't have a Download proress changed event to show the progress of the web page download which leaves you with static(ironically) animation. I ended up going with embedded because it seemed more appropriate at this time.