# Launch Internet explorer from xna game on WP7

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm wondering if I can start Internet Explorer from my XNA game running on Windows Phone 7?

I'd like to redirect my players to my website.

Best regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you can still use the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428757(v=VS.92).aspx).

Use it like this:

```
var wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
wbt.URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
wbt.Show();
```

You'll just need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Phone.dll`

X-REF: [How to launch IE7 from a Windows Phone App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138374/how-to-launch-ie7-from-a-windows-phone-app/4138402#4138402)