# Can't find Microsoft.Phone in references XNA WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I want to open web browser using XNA for WP7,
from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145836/launch-internet-explorer-from-xna-game-on-wp7) I think I must use `WebBrowserTask` to do that,
but I don't know how to add `Microsoft.Phone`

I tried to right click on references but I can't find references `Microsoft.Phone`
I tried just type it in my code, but It still doesn't work..
Anyone know why? am I in the right track?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Phone; // <-- Error here
```

I use VS 2010 Express for windows phone, WP SDK 7.1.1, and Windows 8 Pro

Comment: Please add more information to make it easier for us to help you.  Perhaps even a screenshot of what you have tried and an explanation of what you specifically expected to see and what you specifically saw instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, I can't add screenshots, may be you can download from [here](http://upload.ugm.ac.id/65xna.zip)

Comment: Is your project targeted as a windows phone application? It looks like it is targeted as .Net 4.0 app.

Comment: how I can see my project targeted? I think I targetd as a windows phone game application, I'm using Windows Phone Emulator to run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, on my PC this lib is situated here:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0
  \Profile\WindowsPhone71\Microsoft.Phone.dll
```

You can add it from Solution Explorer:

```
References -> Add reference -> Browse
```

and then paste the path into the File name textbox.