# Open Web Page in Silverlight Windows Phone application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 application written in Silverlight. I have a button in this application. When a user clicks this button, I want it to open the web browser and navigate the user to my website. Is it possible to do this without loading a web browser control in my application? If so how?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch IE7 from a Windows Phone App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138374/how-to-launch-ie7-from-a-windows-phone-app)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28VS.92%29.aspx) class to accomplish that.  Use it as follows:

```
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.URL = "https://www.paypal.com/";
task.Show();
```

Comment: @nickhorn: I have one url and I want to open it from my app. Once user click on that button, first I want to close my app and then want to open that url in browser. Is it possible??