# How to link an image to a website in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

It seems simple but i cannot link an Image to a remote website. 
I've tried HyperlinkButton but i would like to link an image.
How can it be done in Windows phone 7?

Comment: Do you want to use the Image as a link so if you click the image then it navigates to the address?

Comment: I've tried with NavigateService.Navigate but i get an error

Comment: To navigate to a webpage you need a WebBrowser control and you need to use it's Navigate method.

Comment: can't i call an external internet explorer instance?

Comment: In my Answer you will find two link which i think will help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428757%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[How to use the WebBrowserTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138374/how-to-launch-ie7-from-a-windows-phone-app/4138402#4138402)