# Embedding a Website in an App

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to embed a website (that I have no control what-so-ever over) in an app for Windows Phone?

I basically just want an extremely simple app that's just the Google+ website embeded in an app for Windows Phone. I realize I can just pin the website, but it's just not the same as having a nice pretty icon on the start screen, even if it's just a mobile site in a shell.

I know a small amount of C#, so that's the language I'd prefer.

EDIT: I just found this: [How to launch IE7 from a Windows Phone App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138374/how-to-launch-ie7-from-a-windows-phone-app)

So now my question is, how do I use this so it happens on load?

Comment: Just a note that you can create an app like this, but it would probably not make it through the Marketplace certification guidelines, specifically 2.10 - "Your application must have distinct, substantial and legitimate content and purpose. Your application must provide functionality other than launching a webpage." (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841(VS.92).aspx)

Comment: Its just for personal use so it doesn't matter. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you can execute the code that you reference in the above link, in the constructor of your MainPage.xaml.  The question is, though, why?  As you stated, you know you can pin a site, but you want an icon.  Are you aware that you can make the icon appear as any part of the web page you are pinning?  The tile will look like the page you're on, and the view you are at when you pin.  If you want it zoomed out, then zoom out, then pin.  Want an image on the page to be your icon?  Zoom in on that image, and pin.  You have a good deal of flexibility with this, depending on the page, of course.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Unfortunately, Google+ doesn't have a good icon to zoom in on and pin. That's a good tip for other sites though.